# SVN CornerStone Error: Can not commit file

Tags: svn, commit, cornerstone

I'm using CornerStone (v2.7.10) in work with SVN. I dont know why but today I can not commit any file to the repository any more, but updating the working copy is still good. I tried to cancel the commit activity but it took so long, so I decided to quit the application.

Then I reopen CornerStone and try to commit the file again, and it goes:

```
Description : The working copy is locked due to a previous error.
 Suggestion : Clean the working copy and then retry the operation.

Technical Information
=====================

      Error : V4WorkingCopyLockedError
  Exception : ZSVNWorkingCopyLockedException

Causal Information
==================

Description : Working copy '/Users/mac/Documents/Sites/evashop.dev/evashopdevrepo' locked
     Status : 155004
       File : subversion/libsvn_wc/lock.c, 367
```

I tried to clean the working copy and still can not commit files.

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried going to `Working Copy` in the menu bar and clicking `Clean`?

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me. Started uploading my code.

Answer (score 3):

try to clean your Connerstone Working Copy,
select "**Working Copy** -> **Clean**".

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue